# How do I know the length of the video (external FLV video)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How do I know the length of the video (external FLV video)?

I have tried several ways but the result is `0`.

```
videonya.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.READY, onFlvPlayback_READY);

function onFlvPlayback_READY(event:fl.video.VideoEvent):void
{
    var metaDataObj:Object = videonya.metadata as Object;
    trace("metaDataObj.duration: "+metaDataObj.duration);
}
```

Comment: Why not just play the video in a stand-alone player and read the length right from the playhead position?

Comment: I need to know the length of the video to perform other functions on my flash project..

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of playing video and accessing metadata is this:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection(); 
nc.connect(null); 

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc); 
ns.client = this; 
ns.play("video.flv"); 

var vid:Video = new Video(); 
vid.attachNetStream(ns); 
addChild(vid); 

function onMetaData(infoObject:Object):void 
{ 
    var key:String; 
    for (key in infoObject) 
    { 
        trace(key + ": " + infoObject[key]); 
    } 
}
```

This will trace out all of the metadata codes including duration. If you just want the duration: `trace(infoObject.duration);` inside the `onMetaData(infoObject)` function, of course.

Comment: Thanks Craig, i tried your code in my project, but duration = 0. 

duration: 0
videocodecid: 2
videosize: 1148997
filesize: 1313731
videodatarate: 415
audiosize: 164460
width: 320
audiocodecid: 2

Comment: Well, the code is right and your video is, sort of, wrong. The 'videocodeid: 2' means that your video is encoded with the H.263 codec which is an old codec (principally used for videoconferencing) that's officially deprecated in Flash. It probably didn't include duration metadata. You should try to convert it to H.264 (not quite sure with which software). Can you re-encode the original (native format) edited video?

Comment: I should have been more direct: h.263 is not supported in Flash. Can you actually see video when you test your .fla?

Comment: Yes, i can see the video.. Hmmm... do I need to have to convert to other settings?

Comment: I tried .mp4 files with a duration of 1 minute 14 Seconds with your code. The result: duration: 74.30385487528345
avclevel: 21
audiocodecid: mp4a
aacaot: 2
videocodecid: avc1
Conclusion: Several specific types of videos that can be known duration.

Comment: It sounds like you're getting there. 1:14 == 74 sec. Your mp4 is encoded with h.264, right? That's the optimal codec for Flash right now. You can, as you probably know, also use the older ON2 VP6 codec, and a few other battle-axes but I can't think of a good reason to.